# Turn off LCD backlight so that mouse and keyboard do not wake the screen

Tags: xrandr, backlight

I'm trying to accomplish what I had in my old ASUS U36SG laptop: an Fn key turned the screen off. Hitting any key or touching the mouse/touchpad wouldn't wake the screen, only the same Fn combination would work.

In my current laptop, Fn+F2 does what

```
xset dpms force off
```

does. Upon doing any of the above, the backlight just turns back on.

Any other command to accomplish that? A way which doesn't involve any external program (like xbacklight) is preferred, but any is welcome.